# python 3 - assigning the value in function

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter, assign

hi i have function which is called by tinker listbox
so i cannot return the value from it 
basically i have a global object and i want to assign it inside a function
how can i do it

```
    rlink = ('http://stackoverflow', 'pastbin.com', 'unix.com')
    clink  = ' '
    # the function
    def listbinding(*args):
        idxs = reslinkbox.curselection()
        idx = int(idxs[0])

        clink = rlink[idx]
```

i want to rlink[idx] to assign to clink which is a global object
i cannot call the function, tkinter listbox calls the function so i cannot return clink from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`global`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) keyword.

```
 rlink = ('http://stackoverflow', 'pastbin.com', 'unix.com')
 clink  = ' '
 def listbinding(*args):
     global clink
     idxs = reslinkbox.curselection()
     idx = int(idxs[0])

     clink = rlink[idx]
```

`<obligitory>`Using globals like that is more often than not a bad idea as it smears your programs state all over the module rather than having it broken down into nice, discrete chunks. Preventing this is the whole purpose of name spaces. Many computer scientists have spent many years of hard, thankless work to bring you this knowledge.`</obligitory>`

Comment: thanks aaronasterling i had to remove clink = ' ' to get it working correctly

Comment: @aaronasterling: IMHO it should also be obligatory to suggest an alternative.

Comment: @martineau,I agree. However I don't know gui programming and I certainly don't know tkinter. Hence I don't know where the data is coming from or where it eventually needs to end up. It doesn't seem that there's enough information to infer these things even if I did know tkinter. If the asker is interested, he/she should give more information and ask.

Comment: @aaronasterling: OK, you get a pass...but this is, after all, SO, so I'll point out at least one example [Python 2.7.2 global variables + tkinter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865682/python-2-7-2-global-variables-tkinter) to the OP for you. ;-)